# Azure CDN Correct URL Is Pointing A Wrong Resource

Tags: asp.net, azure, cdn, blazor, azure-cdn

I wrote a website with Blazor and because I and my server are in Australia. Most of my friends who want to contribute to my website are in China so I'm using Azure CDN on Azure Blob Storage where I put all the images in, in order to make it faster for visiting in China. The problem is, lots of my friends reported wrong images were displaying in my website and I asked one of my friends to check if the URLs were correct. Turned out, URL was the same but the image it pointed to was completely different. How's that possible? And how to solve things like this?

Edit: Also, I use the self-increment SQL ID as the file name so I can assure new file or the updated file won't use the same name as those deleted or modified files.

[Correct Pointing on My Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOp6O.jpg)
[Wrong Pointing on My Friend's Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CdPP.jpg)

As you can see on the devtool of Chrome, the src are the same but the photos displayed are different.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to purge files.
CDN is replicating your files to local servers, when you update files in storage it does not automatically update all servers. Purging is doing the job.
This is what can be reason, if not this then it sounds very weird for me.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I assign each file a unique self-increment ID (as the file name), which means when I update a specific file, the name will be changed to a brand new ID and IDs shouldn't repeat.